# Listing the sub-items using ionic and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to display the car brand name and sub-list the car model names related to the car brand. But my car model names are displayed as an array and not as a list. Please help me to resolve it.

[Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/V2OuZcheQR51mDRvfgwC?p=info)

```
 <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-model="carBrand" ng-click="selectItem(carBrand)" ng-repeat="name in brandList">
        <div class="item item-divider">
          {{name.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="item">{{name.types}}</div>
        </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Comment: please, post your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ng-repeat for types as `<div class="item" ng-repeat="type in name.types">{{type}}</div>`

```
<ion-content ng-contorller="carBrand">
    <h3> Add/Edit the Car Types </h3>
    {{sample}}
    Make:
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-model="carBrand" ng-click="selectItem(carBrand)" ng-repeat="name in brandList">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                {{name.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="type in name.types">{{type}}</div>
            <br/>
        </ion-item>            
    </ion-list>         
</ion-content>
```